# Meaning of prejudice in the following sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of prejudice in the following sentence

"Think of the **prejudice** that has been documented in Google’s search engines and Amazon’s hiring tools."

**Dictionary meaning:-** a liking or dislike for one rather than another especially without good reason

**Link of article:-** https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2022/jan/09/are-we-witnessing-the-dawn-of-post-theory-science

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: Yes it is in title , i want to understand meaning of prejudice here, added in the body of text also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "prejudice" is being used to mean exactly what the definition you quote says. Google's search engine has been shown to give preference to web pages that express opinions that the people who run Google agree with and to push opinions that Google disagrees with way down the list. I haven't heard similar allegations about Amazon's "hiring tools" but apparently the author is claiming the same sort of prejudice applies.

(The point here is not to discuss the social and political debates around this but the grammar, so I'm not going to get into debating the truth of that statement. If you think that's false, fine, that's not the point. The point is that the person who wrote the original sentence is claiming that it is true.)

Comment: Thanks alot , yes yes I don't want to debate about that , i am just reading articles right now to understand and develop my comprehension, thanks again for the explanation